# Interpretation of coef_ attribute of LogisticRegression class

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a (might be silly) question regarding `coef_` attribute of `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`.

I fit `LogisticRegression` model to `Iris dataset` using only two features(petal width and length). To obtain weights of each feature I use `coef_` attribute and it returns 3x2 array. I understand that the reason I get 3 rows is because of 3 classes and one-vs-rest rule.

However, I can not understand why it includes only w_1 and w_2 (or theta_1 and theta_2, depending on which notation you use), coefficients of feature 1 and 2, but missing w_0 (or theta_0), which is intercept.

Code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data[:, [2,3]]
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)

lr = LogisticRegression(C = 1000, random_state=0)
lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
lr.coef_
```

Comment: could you provide your code?

Comment: I just edited my question and added code also.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The intercept is stored within ```intercept_```.

Comment: @sascha I was looking just for that. You answered my question. Seriously appreciate your help!

Comment: @sascha. I had similar issue, but in my case if I use multilabel binarizer where I have 113 classes and `18013` features, I should get `113 x 18013`?

Answer (score 2):

the attribute 'coef_' gives only the Coefficients of the features in the decision function.

you can get the intercept by using :

```
lr.intercept_
```

Comment: What about using OneVsRest classifier with Logistic regression, what would be the `model.coef_` in this case please?

Answer (score 1):

You might notice the strange-looking trailing underscore at the end
of `coef_` and `intercept_`. Scikit-learn always stores anything
that is derived from the training data in attributes that end with a
trailing underscore. That is to separate them from the parameters that
are set by the user.

`lr.coef_`

> coef_ndarray of shape (1, n_features) or (n_classes, n_features)
> Coefficient of the features in the decision function.
>
> coef_ is of shape (1, n_features) when the given problem is binary. In particular, when multi_class='multinomial', coef_ corresponds to outcome 1 (True) and -coef_ corresponds to outcome 0 (False).

`lr.intercept_`

> intercept_ndarray of shape (1,) or (n_classes,)
> Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to the decision function.
>
> If fit_intercept is set to False, the intercept is set to zero. intercept_ is of shape (1,) when the given problem is binary. In particular, when multi_class='multinomial', intercept_ corresponds to outcome 1 (True) and -intercept_ corresponds to outcome 0 (False).

SOURCE: [Scikit learn Official Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)